# Spring Aspects - How-to expose object fields in a cross-jar project:

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-roo

I'm trying to troubleshoot **this affected type is not exposed to the weaver: com.test.as.Thing1 (needed for privileged access) [Xlint:typeNotExposedToWeaver]**

I have 2 Spring Roo projects.  In "Jar One", I have an object with basic func's:

Thing1.java:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Thing1 {
    private String thingName;
}
```

Thing1_Roo_JavaBean.aj

```
privileged aspect Thing1_JsonFields {
    public String Thing1.getThingName() {
        return this.thingName;
    }

    public void Thing1.setThingName(String thingName) {
        this.thingName = thingName;
    }
}
```

In a second project, "Jar Two", I want to expand on Thing1's capabilities. "Jar Two" has "Jar One" configured as a dependency and has the following aspect:

```
privileged aspect Thing1_Translate {
    public String Thing1.toSpanish() {
        return this.thingName;
    }
    public void Thing1.fromSpanish(String thingName) {
        this.thingName = thingName;
    }
}
```

Here though, in Eclipse I get the following warning:

```
        this.thingName = thingName;

this affected type is not exposed to the weaver: com.test.as.Thing1 (needed for privileged access) [Xlint:typeNotExposedToWeaver]
```

And in the CLI, `mvn package` unit tests complain that the "fromSpanish" and "toSpanish" methods cannot be found.

**How do you expose the private elements cross-jar so that cross-project sub-classes can add / change base behavior?**

There's essentially an identical pom.xml between both projects. viz:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>thingTest</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>thingTest</name>
<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <roo.version>1.2.5.RELEASE</roo.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
        <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
        <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-maven-release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
        <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
        <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>
    <!-- General dependencies for standard applications -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ROO dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.roo</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.roo.annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${roo.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <!-- <configuration> <webXml>target/web.xml</webXml> </configuration> -->
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- NB: You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see MNG-2972) -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outxml>true</outxml>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <!--
                  Aspects in src/main/java and src/main/aspects are added as default in the 
                  compile goal.
                  Aspects in src/test/java and src/test/aspects are added as default in the 
                  test-compile goal.
                  Aspects in src/main/java are added in the test-compile goal 
                  if weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder is set to true
                -->
                <weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>false</weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <printSummary>false</printSummary>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*_Roo_*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- IDE -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <!-- Note 2.8 does not work with AspectJ aspect path -->
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildCommand>
                        <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
                        <arguments>
                            <aspectPath>org.springframework.aspects</aspectPath>
                        </arguments>
                    </buildCommand>
                    <buildCommand>
                        <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                    </buildCommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>com.springsource.sts.roo.core.nature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <dependenciesAsLibraries>true</dependenciesAsLibraries>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.4.v20120524</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
                </webAppConfig>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to weave into another JAR or class file, the latter should be on the *inpath* to make it visible to [ajc](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ajc-ref.html). In AspectJ Maven Plugin there are options like [weaveDependencies](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#weaveDependencies) or *weaveDirectories* for that, respectively. You need to be careful where the woven code goes (to the compiled project's target directory), though, and which module depends on which other project because you weave, then re-weave etc.

An alternative (and maybe better, it depends on your project structure) solution would be to do it the other way around and add the second project to the first project's *aspectpath* go get all weaving done in one place and have the aspects compiled right into the original JAR. In the plugin there is a parameter called [aspectLibraries](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#aspectLibraries) for that purpose.

One way or another, there must be a logical link between dependent projects, otherwise a Java or AspectJ compiler cannot do its job properly.

Comment: Thanks for the direction.  It took me a little while to be able to have cycles to confirm the direction.  But now I have a grasp thanks largely to your feedback.